# What is the difference between maximal flow and maximum flow?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, network-flow

I have tried a lot on internet, but I am unable to get a good answer on the difference between maximal and maximum flow in case of network flow. Anybody has an idea? with example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

- A **maximum flow** is a flow that attains the highest flow value possible for the given network.
- A **maximal flow** is a flow whose value cannot be increased without decreasing the flow along some arc.

All maximum flows are maximal flows. Not all maximal flows are maximum flows.

Figure 3.9 in the [Bang-Jensen and Gutin textbook, first edition](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/books/dbook/) illustrates an example of a flow that is maximal but not maximum.

The difference is very much analogous to the difference between a global optimum and a local optimum.

Answer (score -3):

Both terms refer to the same thing. In the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) article on the maximum flow problem both terms are used equivalently. There you can also find some references to scientific publications that use both terms.